# C++ if statement using fstream not working

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I'm currently doing the bunny challenge on [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/). I'm writing all the bunnies in a text file, and then writing their gender & color into an array. I am reading the genders and ages from the text file. I have this one problem though: even though both the value 'sexT is == "male"', the if statement returns false.

```
void turn()
{
string *bunnyArray1 = new string[numberOfElements];
string *bunnyArray2 = new string[numberOfElements];
int id, males = 0, females = 0;
string sexT, colorT;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
{
    string buffer;
    reader >> id;
    if (i == 0 || (double)i / 5 == (int)i / 5)
    {
        reader >> sexT;
        reader >> colorT;
        reader >> colorT;
        if (sexT == "male") { males++; }
        else if (sexT == "female") { females++; }
        bunnyArray1[id] = sexT;
        bunnyArray2[id] = colorT;
        cout << females << " " << males << endl;
    }

}



        delete[]bunnyArray1;
        delete[]bunnyArray2;
}
```

The output is following:

```
A spotted male bunny named Sean has been born.
A black male bunny named Sean has been born.
A spotted female bunny named Andrea has been born.
A brown male bunny named John has been born.
A spotted female bunny named Andrea has been born.
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
```

So for some reason it says there is 5 males, even though there is 3. The output of the file is:

```
1
male
Sean
spotted
false
2
male
Sean
black
false
3
female
Andrea
spotted
true
4
male
John
brown
false
5
female
Andrea
spotted
false
```

I really can't figure out why it is not working.
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: A couple of hints: Don't use explicit dynamic memory allocation, use containers like std::vector. Always check the return value of an input function such as >>.

Comment: There is more code right? Its difficult to know whats wrong without seeing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is `(double)i / 5 == (int)i / 5` for? If you want to know if `i` is a multiple of 5, use `i%5 == 0`. And there's no need to check for `0` separately, that will be true with this test.

Comment: What's the point of `    if (i == 0 || (double)i / 5 == (int)i / 5)` in the first place? This means you'll only read the sex and other information after reading every 5th ID. But that's not how the file is organized.

Comment: You've miscounted too, so don't be too hard on the program ;-)

Comment: The '(double)i / 5 == (int)i / 5' is for finding out if the current line is the identifier, as it will activaye every five lines then. I have tried to 'cout << sexT' where it would output "male" but when I put it in a if statement it returns false.